# Liquibase and H2 problem with not existing table

Tags: database, h2, liquibase

I have a problem with liquibase and H2 database. I wanted to add some testing to my liquibase schema on push to github via github workflow. So I have decided to make a SpringBoot profile with H2 to make it work. And almost everything works. In two cases, I add constraints via sql and it gives me an exception telling that this table does not exist. When I comment those sql statements, then the whole thing works like a charm.
So, here is my yaml file for test profile:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:task_schema;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=PostgreSQL;IGNORECASE=TRUE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS TASK_SCHEMA
    username: sa
    password:
    initialization-mode: always
  liquibase:
    default-schema: task_schema
    drop-first: true
    change-log: classpath:/database/changelogs/changelog-master.xml
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    openInView: false
    show_sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    properties:
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.generate_statistics: true
```

changelog with interesting changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <include file="create-client-sequence.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="create-client-table.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="add-client-name-constraint.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

create-client-table.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet author="liquibase" id="create-client-table">
        <createTable tableName="CLIENT">
            <column name="ID" type="${long.type}">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="UUID" type="UUID">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="FIRST_NAME" type="VARCHAR2(32 ${char.unit})">
                <constraints nullable="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="LAST_NAME" type="VARCHAR2(32 ${char.unit})">
                <constraints  nullable="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="COMPANY_NAME" type="VARCHAR2(32 ${char.unit})">
                <constraints  nullable="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="EMAIL" type="VARCHAR2(50 ${char.unit})"/>
            <column name="NOTE" type="VARCHAR2(1000 ${char.unit})"/>
            <column name="TELEPHONE" type="VARCHAR2(20 ${char.unit})"/>
            <column name="PROJECTS_VALUE" type="${big_decimal.type}" defaultValueNumeric="0.0">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="CLIENT_TYPE" type="VARCHAR2(20 ${char.unit})">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="POST_CODE" type="VARCHAR2(6 ${char.unit})"/>
            <column name="CITY" type="VARCHAR2(30 ${char.unit})"/>
            <column name="STREET" type="VARCHAR2(30 ${char.unit})"/>
            <column name="HOUSE_NUMBER" type="VARCHAR2(5 ${char.unit})"/>
            <column name="FLAT_NUMBER" type="VARCHAR2(5 ${char.unit})"/>
        </createTable>
        <addPrimaryKey tableName="CLIENT" columnNames="ID" constraintName="PK_CLIENT"/>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

and add-client-name-constraint.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet author="liquibase" id="add-client-name-constraint">
        <sql>
            alter table CLIENT add constraint NAME_NOT_NULL
            check
            (
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'PRIVATE') and ((FIRST_NAME is NOT NULL) AND (LAST_NAME is NOT NULL))) or
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'CORPORATE') and (COMPANY_NAME is NOT NULL))
            );
        </sql>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

and some part of stack trace (sorry for Polish there):

```
2021-06-07 20:49:29.122  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] l.e.j.JdbcExecutor                       : CREATE TABLE TASK_SCHEMA.CLIENT (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, UUID UUID NOT NULL, FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(32), LAST_NAME VARCHAR(32), COMPANY_NAME VARCHAR(32), EMAIL VARCHAR(50), NOTE VARCHAR(1000), TELEPHONE VARCHAR(20), PROJECTS_VALUE DECIMAL(19, 6) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, CLIENT_TYPE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, POST_CODE VARCHAR(6), CITY VARCHAR(30), STREET VARCHAR(30), HOUSE_NUMBER VARCHAR(5), FLAT_NUMBER VARCHAR(5))
2021-06-07 20:49:29.123  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] l.c.ChangeSet                            : Table CLIENT created
2021-06-07 20:49:29.123  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] l.e.j.JdbcExecutor                       : ALTER TABLE TASK_SCHEMA.CLIENT ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENT PRIMARY KEY (ID)
2021-06-07 20:49:29.124  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] l.c.ChangeSet                            : Primary key added to CLIENT (ID)
2021-06-07 20:49:29.124  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] l.c.ChangeSet                            : ChangeSet classpath:/database/changelogs/v1.0.0/client/create-client-table.xml::create-client-table::liquibase ran successfully in 3ms
2021-06-07 20:49:29.124  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] l.e.j.JdbcExecutor                       : INSERT INTO TASK_SCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES ('create-client-table', 'liquibase', 'classpath:/database/changelogs/v1.0.0/client/create-client-table.xml', NOW(), 4, '8:9f420f03a34211b142d310064019080e', 'createTable tableName=CLIENT; addPrimaryKey constraintName=PK_CLIENT, tableName=CLIENT', '', 'EXECUTED', NULL, NULL, '3.10.1', '3091768994')
2021-06-07 20:49:29.129  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] l.e.j.JdbcExecutor                       : alter table CLIENT add constraint NAME_NOT_NULL
            check
            (
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'PRIVATE') and ((FIRST_NAME is NOT NULL) AND (LAST_NAME is NOT NULL))) or
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'CORPORATE') and (COMPANY_NAME is NOT NULL))
            )
2021-06-07 20:49:29.130 ERROR 1607585 --- [           main] l.c.ChangeSet                            : Change Set classpath:/database/changelogs/v1.0.0/client/add-client-name-constraint.xml::add-client-name-constraint::liquibase failed.  Error: Tabela "CLIENT" nie istnieje
Table "CLIENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table CLIENT add constraint NAME_NOT_NULL
            check
            (
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'PRIVATE') and ((FIRST_NAME is NOT NULL) AND (LAST_NAME is NOT NULL))) or
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'CORPORATE') and (COMPANY_NAME is NOT NULL))
            ) [42102-200] [Failed SQL: (42102) alter table CLIENT add constraint NAME_NOT_NULL
            check
            (
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'PRIVATE') and ((FIRST_NAME is NOT NULL) AND (LAST_NAME is NOT NULL))) or
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'CORPORATE') and (COMPANY_NAME is NOT NULL))
            )]
2021-06-07 20:49:29.131  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] l.l.StandardLockService                  : Successfully released change log lock
2021-06-07 20:49:29.132  WARN 1607585 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:/database/changelogs/v1.0.0/client/add-client-name-constrain.xml::add-client-name-constraint::liquibase:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Tabela "CLIENT" nie istnieje
Table "CLIENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table CLIENT add constraint NAME_NOT_NULL
            check
            (
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'PRIVATE') and ((FIRST_NAME is NOT NULL) AND (LAST_NAME is NOT NULL))) or
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'CORPORATE') and (COMPANY_NAME is NOT NULL))
            ) [42102-200] [Failed SQL: (42102) alter table CLIENT add constraint NAME_NOT_NULL
            check
            (
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'PRIVATE') and ((FIRST_NAME is NOT NULL) AND (LAST_NAME is NOT NULL))) or
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'CORPORATE') and (COMPANY_NAME is NOT NULL))
            )]
2021-06-07 20:49:29.133  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor           : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-06-07 20:49:29.133  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-06-07 20:49:29.136  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                   : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-06-07 20:49:29.142  INFO 1607585 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
```

I will appreciate any help.

EDIT:
Solved. For h2 SQL I have added schema name before table name and it works. The strange part of it is, that if I run H2 in console, it does not require that. So now, the file looks like this:
and add-client-name-constraint.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">

    <changeSet author="liquibase" id="add-client-name-constraint">
        <sql dbms="postgresql">
            alter table CLIENT add constraint NAME_NOT_NULL
            check
            (
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'PRIVATE') and ((FIRST_NAME is NOT NULL) AND (LAST_NAME is NOT NULL))) or
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'CORPORATE') and (COMPANY_NAME is NOT NULL))
            );
        </sql>
        <sql dbms="h2">
            alter table TASK_SCHEMA.CLIENT add constraint NAME_NOT_NULL
            check
            (
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'PRIVATE') and ((FIRST_NAME is NOT NULL) AND (LAST_NAME is NOT NULL))) or
            ((CLIENT_TYPE = 'CORPORATE') and (COMPANY_NAME is NOT NULL))
            );
        </sql>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if your `create-client-table.xml` was ran successfully without any errors? When I executed these SQLs on postgres DB, I didn't get the error you mentioned.

Comment: On Postgres I don't have any problems either. This code runs and constraints do their job. Problem is only when I want to run it on H2 to test changelogs. Only there I have issues. As I wrote in my post, I created this profile to test changelogs on push to GitHub with the use of GitHub workflow.

Comment: were you to fix this, I have same issue?@ArturJarosz

Comment: @a_a Yes. As I have edited my original post, making separate scripts for H2 and the main database worked. In the H2 part (with dbms="h2") I added the schema name in front of the table name and it worked.